# I'm using jquery and regular javascript on a page with no probs until I added one more function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I'm doing.

I have a few images on a page with an HTML5 audio player underneath each one and a select menu with a list of sounds.

When a sound is selected from the menu, it places that sound in the source of the audio player.

What I want to do is change the image to an animated gif when the sound is played.

The onchange works fine loading the sound into the player.  But when I add the new onplay() call, none of the javascript works.

```js
function playPic(theid){
var leid = theid.replace('play','');
document.getElementById('leid'+pic).src="images/" + leid ".gif";
}

  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );


 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sortable').sortable();
   //$('<br><br><div id=buttonDiv><button>Get Order of Elements</button></div>').appendTo('body');
   //$('button').button().click(function() {
   
   $( "#sendgame" ).submit(function( event ) {
   var itemOrder = $('#sortable').sortable("toArray");
   var fullOrder = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {
   newi = i + 1;
    //alert("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i]);
        fullOrder += newi + " - " + itemOrder[i] + "<br>";    
                }
 //alert  (fullOrder);
 document.forms["sendgame"].ordre.value = fullOrder;
            })
        });



function recSon(lename, leson) {
document.forms["sendgame"][lename].value = leson;
}



  function loudSon(soundid, leplayer) {
  
  lesound = "";
   if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
 lesound = soundid + ".ogg";
 } else {
 lesound = soundid + ".mp3";
 }
 }
```

The playPic function is what screws everything up.  I've tried it in different places in the code but always the same error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: recSon is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (jeuhockeynoir.php?lang=f:481)
onchange @ jeuhockeynoir.php?lang=f:481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a `+` sign:

`document.getElementById('leid'+pic).src="images/" + leid ".gif";`

should be

`document.getElementById('leid'+pic).src="images/" + leid + ".gif";`